# Show that $\liminf_{n\to\infty} nx_{n}=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }x_{n}$ be a convergent series of positive real numbers. Show that $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} nx_{n}=0$$
I don't really know if it is just some theorem, but please help, I have no clue on these subjects, thanks

Comment: What does $\inf(\lim) nx_{n}=0$ mean?  Do you mean $\liminf_{n\to\infty}nx_n=0$?  Something else?  I can't make sense of what you've written.

Comment: yeah, thats right, it's lim inf, sorry, I'm really bad at maths

Comment: Write down what you know.  What does it mean to say that the $\liminf$ is $0$?  What does it mean to say that the $\liminf$ is not $0$.  If the $\liminf$ is not $0$, would the series converge?

Comment: I'm just guessing, I mean anything I would say, it's just dumb, I would probably say that the series doesn't converge if the limit would be +/- infinity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that this wasn't the case and that $\liminf_{n\to\infty}nx_n\neq 0$. There are two cases:

Case 1: $\liminf_{n\to\infty}nx_n=s>0$. By definition, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $nx_n>\frac{s}{2}$. But then

$$\sum_{n=N}^\infty x_n>\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{s}{2n}=\frac{s}{2}\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{n}=\infty$$

Case 2: $\liminf_{n\to\infty}nx_n=\infty$. This is similar to the first case. By definition, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $nx_n>1$. From here, the same logic applies to conclude

$$\sum_{n=N}^\infty x_n>\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{n}=\infty$$

Either way, we run into a contradiction. We conclude

$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}nx_n= 0$$

Comment: can you please explain the part with by definition, there exists N etc , I don't really get why n is bigger than N and how you got to the nxn> s/2, thanks

Comment: @Not_Important Do you know what a limit is?

Comment: yes, but I don't really to math all that much, I'll understand from the solution

Comment: So the limit inferior can be thought of the 'minimum' of a sequence over time. Of course, minimum isn't the right word, (infimum is better) but it is also similar to the greatest lower bound of a sequence. Again, this is not quite right since a sequence can have an infinite number of members less than the liminf. Look https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior for more information

Comment: ok thanks, I'll look more about that